# Angular, accessing router params in a service

Tags: angular, observable, store, ngrx, behaviorsubject

We have a menu object (menu store) that several components will use to populate data.

when loading a page I would like to have the menu loaded from server and expose it as a store

```
private subject = new BehaviorSubject<Menu>(state);
private menuStore = this.subject.asObservable().filter((m) => m != undefined).distinctUntilChanged();
```

Then each component get the result

```
    menu$ = this.menuStore.select<MenuItem>('menu');
```

So the question I have is this... Currently we do actions in the constructor of our "menuService". As i understand it this is not really best practice as it's not under Angulars control(?).

So how should we do this? Should we use "implements OnInit" in the menu.store.ts? or is it valid and ok to do this in the constructor and might this give us problems down the road?

Comment: The lifecycle hooks are only for *components*.

Comment: Ah.. great! I was kind of suspecting that.. but then how can we do this without subscribing in all components?

Comment: Services do hava a `ngOnDestroy` hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating "PageComponents" and in those components subscribing

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  this.menuService.setActiveItem(params.id)
})
```